# Smart macro to produce stanzas

Tags: spacing, plain-tex, poetry

I want to typeset a booklet of poetry, in Plain. Thus far I've been able to make TeX obey spaces and lines with the following code:

```
\def\startline{\par\noindent}
\obeylines\obeyspaces
\let^^M=\startline
\raggedright
\everypar{\hangindent=2em}
```

However, the macros swallow the double ^^M that should mark the space between stanzas.

```
  On the white sand
Of the beach of a small island
In the Eastern Sea

  I, my face streaked with tears,
Am playing with a crab

   – Ishikawa Takuboku
```

How can I teach TeX to catch the double line feeds to produce the vertical space needed?

[image: tanka]

**Addendum**

@egreg and @Steven's answers almost do the job, but in the simple case the vertical space is determined by the `\baselineskip` of `\par`; to make the problem more interesting, let's say I borrow the definition of `\@ifnextchar` from LaTeX and I define

```
\parindent=0em
\def\stanza{\leavevmode\vskip 1ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}
\long\def\normalpar{\expandafter\par}
\long\def\checkpar{\@ifnextchar^^M\stanza\normalpar}
\obeylines\obeyspaces
\let^^M=\checkpar%
\raggedright%
\everypar{\hangindent=2em}%
```

As you see, at every `^^M` I'm trying to check `\@ifnextchar` is another `^^M`; if so, add stanza vertical space defined in `\stanza`; otherwise, add a regular `\par`. My problem is that I don't know how to tell the processor that the next token to check for is precisely the line feed character. The idea is to avoid the default vertical space assumed by the `\baselineskip` on regular lines.

Comment: If I get it right, both @Steven and @egreg's first answers are based on the idea of entering horizontal mode immediately at the end of the current paragraph or at the beginning of the next one, either by simply saying `\leavevmode` or by inserting a `\hbox`; however, in either case the vertical space is assumed to be determined by `\baselineskip`. Is there a way to get some control on it? Am I asking a different question?

Comment: For the addendum: move the definition of `\checkpar` after `\obeylines`. And remember `%` at the end of the line.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and the stanza vertical spaces are added right, but the `\obeyspaces` is now ignored. Didn't figure out why.

Comment: You are using the wrong approach: if you remove markup, you give no clue for how to decide what a blank line should be. Note that you can't test a blank line by checking whether `^^M` immediately follows `^^M`, because spaces could be on that line. But if you remove spaces, you can't have indentation on the first verse of a stanza. Well, it *can* be done, but is it worth the effort?

Comment: But then you have no indentation where specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have an empty line where indicated by the blank line, add `\leavevmode` to `\startline`. Rather than issuing `\noindent` each time, it's better to set `\parindent` to zero.

Also some `%` are missing after `\obeylines` starts having effect; you couldn't see the issue with your code, just because a `\par` in vertical mode gave nothing.

```
\parindent=0pt
\def\startline{\par\leavevmode}
\obeylines\obeyspaces
\let^^M=\startline%
\raggedright%
\everypar{\hangindent=2em}%

  On the white sand
Of the beach of a small island
In the Eastern Sea

  I, my face streaked with tears,
Am playing with a crab

   --- Ishikawa Takuboku

\bye
```

[image]

The next version *requires* that a blank line is *really empty*, so you can control also the space between stanzas (and the final attribution).

Maybe one can also cope with taking care of spaces, but it's difficult and not worthy the effort. Your approach is wrong to begin with: no mark up means no flexibility.

```
\obeylines\obeyspaces
\parindent=0pt%
\def\endline{%
  \par%
  \let\savedspaces\empty%
  \futurelet\next\perhapseol%
}%
\def\perhapseol{%
  \ifx\next^^M%
    \let\nxt\newstanza%
  \else%
    \let\nxt\leavevmode%
  \fi%
  \nxt%
}%
\def\newstanza#1{\vskip50pt#1}% exaggerated to show the effect
\let^^M=\endline%
\raggedright%
\everypar{\hangindent=2em}%

  On the white sand
Of the beach of a small island
In the Eastern Sea

  I, my face streaked with tears,
Am playing with a crab

   --- Ishikawa Takuboku

\catcode`\^^M=5

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here I add a null `\hbox` to the `\everypar`.  What this does is force two blank lines to be interpreted as `\par\hbox{}\par` rather than `\par\par`.  In the latter case, TeX collapses it down to a single `\par`, which is not wanted here.

```
\def\startline{\par\noindent}
\obeylines\obeyspaces
\let^^M=\startline
\raggedright
\everypar{\hbox to 0pt{}\hangindent=2em}

  On the white sand
Of the beach of a small island
In the Eastern Sea

  I, my face streaked with tears,
Am playing with a crab

   -– Ishikawa Takuboku
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, a fairly general solution might be, assuming loading `\@ifnextchar` from `miniltx.tex`,

```
\input miniltx
\makeatletter
\parindent=0em
\def\stanzasp#1{\edef\@stanzasp{\vskip#1\relax}}
\def\normalpar{\par\leavevmode}
\obeylines\obeyspaces
\def\checkpar{\@ifnextchar^^M\@stanzasp\normalpar}%
\let^^M=\checkpar%
\raggedright%
\everypar{\hangindent=2em}%
\makeatother%
\stanzasp{2ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}
```

The macro `\stanzasp` takes a dimension as an argument; in this example it is set to `2ex plus 1ex minus 1ex`, but you may adjust it according to your taste (or lack thereof).